# R version 3.4.1 error in install.packages(ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rtools

I am having some trouble installing packages on R, and I'm not sure what to do. The errors are as follows:
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\XanDesktop\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpyy8lER\downloaded_packages

> install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XanDesktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘rlang’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
rlang    0.3.4 0.4.11              TRUE
ggplot2  3.1.1  3.3.5             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/XanDesktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/file4c04705ac2/rlang/help/figures/rlang.png': Permission denied

> 

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is possibly due to your version of R being 4 years old (btw, you are confusing R with R Studio). Update R to its latest version (v4.1.1) and try installing the packages again.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).